# Delphi XE7 and BDE TStoredProc trouble?

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe7, bde

I have to migrate an old Delphi 4/BDE/Firebird 1.5. As a first step, I would like to convert it under Delphi XE7/BDE/Firebird 1.5. When all or most of migration bugs will be corrected I'll update Firebird and may later change the BDE.

But I have trouble with a simple use of a `TStoredProc` with doesn't return any values in his params list after an `ExecProc`.

Under Delphi 4, to test on a new project, I put a `TDatabase` and a `TStoredProc` component. In the `FormShow`, I wrote this simple code:

```pascal
if not Database1.Connected then
  Database1.Connected := True;
with VerifUser2 do
begin
  DatabaseName := Database1.DatabaseName;
  Params[0].AsInteger := 1;
  Params[1].AsString := 'nico';
  Params[2].AsString := '';
  ExecProc;
  ShowMessage(ParamByName('IP_USER').AsString);
end;
```

The good value, '10061' for this test, is shown using `ParamByName('IP_USER')` or `Params[3]`.

I do the same thing under Delphi XE7, new form, put the two components and the connection with my Firebird database seems good and I chose a stored procedure at design time.

But at run time I always have '0' either using `ParamByName` or `Params[3]`.

Using FireDac, I can read the good value but as I have a lot of BDE components and a lot of code I don't like to have to convert Delphi codes and change the BDE layer at the same time.

**Update 1:** As asked, here is the SQL code of the procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_VERIF_USER (
  XID_MASTER Integer,
  XLOG Varchar(20),
  XPASS Varchar(13) )
RETURNS (
  IP_USER Integer,
  IP_PROFIL Integer,
  LIB_USER Varchar(50),
  LOG_USER Varchar(20),
  PASS_USER Varchar(13),
  ERR_MSG Varchar(100) )
AS
  Declare variable vexclu char(1);
  Declare variable vitmp integer;
begin
  ip_user = 0;
  Err_Msg = '';
  FOR SELECT
    SO.IP_SOCIETE,
    SO.SOCIETE_CLE,
    SO.SOCIETE_EAN13,
    SO.SOCIETE_RAISON_SOCIALE,
    SO.SOCIETE_EXCLU,
    SO.ID_CLASSE_PRINCIPALE
  FROM SOCIETE SO
  WHERE
    (SO.ID_MASTER = 1) AND
    (SO.IDS_SOCIETE_TYPE = 'U') AND
    (SO.SOCIETE_CLE = CHARUPPER(:xlog)) AND
    (SCOMPARE(SO.SOCIETE_EAN13, :xpass)=0)
  PLAN (SOCIETE INDEX (FIX_SOCIETE_CLE))
  INTO :ip_user, :log_user, :pass_user, :lib_user, :vexclu, :ip_profil
  DO
  BEGIN
    IF ((Err_Msg = '') and (icompare(ip_profil,0)<>0)) THEN
    BEGIN
     SELECT      F_SUBSTR(CHR(13)||:XID_MASTER||CHR(13),CHR(13)||OBJET_LIBELLE||CHR(13))
     FROM OBJET
     WHERE IP_OBJET = :ip_profil
     INTO :vitmp;
       if (vitmp >- 1) then Err_Msg = '%s : Utilisateur non autorisé dans   cette société ';
  END
    IF (Err_Msg <> '') THEN
    BEGIN
      ip_user = 0;
      EXIT;
    END
 END
 IF (ip_user=0) THEN
   Err_Msg = '%s : Utilisateur ou mot de passe inconnu';
 end^
```

As this works under Delphi 4/BDE and Delphi XE7/FireDac I don't think that the trouble could come from this but you never know.

**Update 2** : I have added a suspend in my procedure and use a BDE `TQuery` with an `SELECT * FROM PROC_VERIF_USER(:master,:username,:password)` and i read the data with `FieldByName()` and it works...

I really have a trouble with the BDE `TStoredProc` component...

I'm going to try an other procedure of my database just to be sure that the trouble don't come from the procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: We can't see the data or the code for the stored procedure, I'm not sure how we can help without more information.

Comment: Hello, the  ` IF (Err_Msg <> '') ` is in the ` FOR SELECT ` and force the return with in error message in case of the user profile isn't allowed. The other test    IF (ip_user=0) THEN    is outside the    FOR SELECT in case of the user name isn't found. But, i don't think that the trouble come from the stored procedure as she returns values under Delphi 4/BDE and Delphi XE7/FireDac. The problem is under Delphi XE7/BDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL** Well i found my solution in fact is really simple when you know it...
Replacing the `Params[x].AsString` with `Params[x].AsAnsiString` works!!
I found this solution a few hours after the Update 2 but didn't have the time to report it. Sorry.
Thanks for you help.